# Problem answering calls on with Moto G (2nd generation) with Lollipop

Tags: calls, motorola-moto-g2

When I receive a call I am not able to answer the call. When I try to move answer option to right it moves but call is not getting received. After that it just shows there is missed call and on other device it shows my phone is still ringing. But when there call for second time I am able to receive it without any interruption. What can I do?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange! Have you tried phoning Motorola for advice? What did they say?

Comment: Also, which version of Lollipop are you using: 5.0, or 5.1?

Comment: What happens if you attend the call using an headset?